# Metrics of degree higher than 2

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Suppose I have a metric (special relativity) as follows:

$$
(ds)^2 = -(dt)^2+(dx)^2+(dy)^2+(dz)^2  \tag{1}
$$

Here there are no cross-terms. Let's consider for instance this metric (which could be used in general relativity, and has cross-terms):

$$
(ds)^2=-(dt)^2+(dx)^2+(dy)^2+(dz)^2+(dxdy)+... \tag{2}
$$

Both the previous metrics have "degree 2". I am interested in metrics that are of "degree 4". For example:

$$
(ds)^4=(dt)^4+(dx)^4+2(dx)^2(dy)^2+(dx)^3dy+... \tag{3}
$$

We note that this metric cannot be written as a polynomial of degree 2.

---

How can I work with such a metric using conventional tools?

---

For instance, in special relativity (equation 1), I can write the metric as a tensor:

$$
(ds)^2=\pmatrix{dt&dx&dy&dz}\pmatrix{-1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1}\pmatrix{dt\\dx\\dy\\dz}\tag{4}
$$

How can I write $(ds)^4$ (equation 3) as a metric tensor using a similar form as equation 4, but adapted to a degree 4 metric polynomial?

Comment: What would such a metric measure?

Comment: Why can’t there be cross terms in the original metric? Its expression as a quadratic form depends on the choice of coordinate system.

Comment: @amd Equation 2 has cross-terms such as dxdy. But equation 3 has cross-terms such as dxdxdxdy that cannot be formed in a degree 2 metric.

Comment: My point is that counter to the claim that you make in the second sentence, there can be “cross terms” in the metric without bringing general relativity into the picture.

Comment: @amd I am just giving a few examples of various metrics to set the context of the question. I'll edit the offensive part. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I would assume the distance between two points (in non-Euclidean/non-general-relativistic space).

Comment: I think you're putting the cart before the horse.  How exactly would you use a symmetric degree four tensor to construct a distance function.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang So $ds=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$ is the distance function of the Euclidean metric, right? Then $ds=\sqrt[4]{(dx^2+dy^2)^2}$ is the distance function of a fourth degree metric. Another one could be $ds=\sqrt[4]{dx^4+dy^4}$, or $ds=\sqrt[4]{dx^4+dy^4+2dx^3dy}$.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing $ds^2=g_{ab}dx^adx^b$ with $g$ symmetric, you'd want $ds^4=g_{abcd}dx^adx^bdx^cdx^d$ with $g$ fully symmetric. But there are very good theoretical reasons physicists work with degree-$2$ metrics, such as wanting to be able to move indices viz.$$dx_a=g_{ab}dx^b\implies ds^2=dx_adx^a,\,dx^b=g^{bc}dx_c\implies dx_a=g_{ab}g^{bc}dx_c\implies g_{ab}g^{bc}=\delta_a^c.$$

Comment: So $g_{abcd}$ is a $4\times4\times4\times4$ object?

Comment: @ALexandreH.Tremblay In an $n$-dimensional spacetime it's $n\times n\times n\times n$, yes. It's called a rank-$4$ tensor.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep in mind that the metric in GR is a "semi-definite bi-linear symmetric form on every tangent space that varies smoothly with the base point". In the same manner you can define a symmetric n-linear form on every tangent space ($n \geq 2$ can be whatever you want), but you wouldn't call it a "metric".

Comment: A "metric" of degree 4 could follow all of the axioms of a mathematical metric : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics) , or do you mean something else?

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay You're thinking of definite metrics rather than indefinite ones.

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay a metric in differential geometry is a function that takes 2 tangent vectors in space time and spits out a number (and is symmetric on the arguments and a bunch of other things). A "metric of degree 4" you described would have to take 4 tangent vectors as arguments, not 2. You can imagine taking just 2 tangent vectors and replicating them in the remaining 2 spots if that is something useful for what you are doing, but you wouldn't call it a metric, because in differential geometry that is a term reserved for a different thing.

Comment: Also, to elaborate what @J.G. said: the term "metric" used in differential geometry (and GR) doesn't have the same meaning of "metric" in a "Metric Space". They are referring to two different things